# how do I control output from angular-moment

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I am using [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) library. Essentially, I want to show the time difference in minutes between now and some time in the model. Ideally, the display must be dynamic; so the user doesn't need to refresh the page in order to see updates.

`<span am-time-ago="message.time"></span>` works and works dynamically. **But** it shows user-friendly messages "a few seconds ago, 2 minutes ago, etc. I need the actual value in minutes (30 means in 30 minutes, -120 means I am 2 hours late, etc.)

Everything else, for example `moment(myJsonValue).diff(moment(), 'minutes')` is not dynamic. Is there a way to have both dynamic **and** numeric?